# Meteor require unpublished npm module

Tags: meteor, npm

In node, it's easy to do

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.3",
    "PACKAGE_NAME": "git://github.com/USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git#COMMIT_SHA"
  }
```

In meteor I can include an npm module using `var uuid = Meteor.npmRequire('node-uuid');` for npm packages that are published, but when pointing my package at github (the same way I would in a node project) I get an error.

How does one doe this with Meteor? When trying to do the same thing in the package.json I get the following error 
    "must declare exact version of dependency:"

Any help on how to include a package that's not published to Npm?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the commit and point to the archive. From https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm:

> If you need to install an npm module from a specific commit, use the
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> {   "googleapis": "https://github.com/bradvogel/google-api-nodejs-client/archive/d945dabf416d58177b0c14da64e0d6038f0cc47b.tar.gz" }
> ```